# Set table's body range and all cells below it as unlocked

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set the union of the table's body range and all of the cells below the table to unlocked. How can I do this? More specifically I don't know how to target the area below the table...

Comment: `tableObject.DataBodyRange.Resize(10000)` or some other reasonable size, unless you really mean all the way to the bottom of the sheet

Comment: I mean all the way to the bottom of the sheet.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```vb
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows(1)
    .Resize(1 + Rows.Count - .Row).Locked = False
    Debug.Print "Unlocked", .Resize(1 + Rows.Count - .Row).Address
End With
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken this solution only populates rows inside the table? I also want to target rows below the table.

Comment: You might be mistaken - did you test it?  Added a `debug.print` above for confirmation

Comment: Note `Rows.Count` has no `.` so it references the worksheet, not the listobject's first row

Answer (score 0):

### Referencing Ranges

```vb
Sub ReferencingRanges()
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") _
        .ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
    
    Dim drg As Range
    
    With srg
        
        ' Reference the range.
        Set drg = .Cells
        Debug.Print "DataBodyRange: " & drg.Address(0, 0)
        
        ' Reference the range below the range.
        Set drg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - .Rows.Count + 1) _
            .Offset(.Rows.Count)
        Debug.Print "Below... :     " & drg.Address(0, 0)
        
        ' Reference the range and the range below the range.
        Set drg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        Debug.Print "Both... :      " & drg.Address(0, 0)
    
    End With
    
    'drg.Locked = False
    
End Sub
```